# Automatic click on a pop up button

Tags: javascript, web, browser, greasemonkey

I've the following button that appear suddenly on a window.

```
<span class="a b c" id="PulsingButton_6_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Accept Waiting Chat</span>
```

Would be possible to intercept it and automatically click on it?
I was thinking at something in JS or a greasemonkey extension.

Ideas?

Comment: See [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](//stackoverflow.com/q/15048223).

Comment: it's possible for sure but it will most likely be the wrong way to solve your problem. If you don't want the button to show you should understand why it is showing in the first place and fix that part of the code. In any case you should also post your effort in solving the problem so people will be more likely to help you here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't want to avoid the button to pop up, I just want to click click on it automatically when will popup. I tried to solve it by myself in different ways but all were wrong. I tried this in greasemonkey   var evt = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent ("click", true, true);
document.getElementByID('PulsingButton_6_label').dispatchEvent (evt);  Doesn't work, I asked help, because I don't know how to approch the problem