# How to use autoclick a button as soon as it pops up on a browser with tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

So I have seen multiple questions on this but i don't think i have seen one that has been solved.
I am also super new to JS, jQuery and I have never made a userscript before so I still dont know a lot of words or concepts.
So feel free to dumb it down for me :).

I want to autoclick a particular button on a site that pops up only for a split second.
Tons of people are trying to click on the same button so you have to be lightning fast.

I wanted to make a script to make this process easier.

I use an auto refresh extension to help refresh the page which i would like to use with the script as well.

***What im struggling with:***

**1. Create a userscript with tampermonkey and javascript/jquery to locate and auto click the  button.**

**2. The button is not on the page from the start and only pops up for a few seconds.**

**3. The page is constantly refreshing but I wanted to make sure the script will keep trying to click the button till it pops up and then stop once clicked.**

***My attempts so far:***

Ive tried multiple site, extensions and questions here on stack:

1. [How to auto click an input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069232/how-to-auto-click-an-input-button)
2. [Automatic click on a pop up button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553882/automatic-click-on-a-pop-up-button)
3. Extension Autoclicker (really good btw): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-clicker-autofill/iapifmceeokikomajpccajhjpacjmibe?hl=en
4. Extension imacros (also decent) : [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en#:~:text=You%20can%20combine%20iMacros%20with,iMacros%20for%20Firefox%20without%20changes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en#:%7E:text=You%20can%20combine%20iMacros%20with,iMacros%20for%20Firefox%20without%20changes)!

MY ATTEMPT TO MAKE THE PROGRAM WITH TAMPERMONKEY AND jQUERY:
**I use a Tampermonkey extension that will allow jQuery on all pages just FYI**

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         Autoclicker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        Name
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const clickButton = () => {
        const button =
              document.querySelector("#queue-0-1394263709")
        if (button) button.click()
        else setTimeout(clickButton, 500)
    }
    window.addEventListener("DOMcontentloaded", clickButton)
})();
```

*This was just me trying something with the limited jQuery I know.

The Button details:
**Xpath of button:**   //*[@id="queue-0-1319022196"]

**Selector of button:**  `#queue-0-1394263709`

**Button:** `<a href="#" data="[object Object]" id="queue-0-1394263709" name="queue_item">Start</a>`

PS: The button does not have a class to the best of my knowledge.
I would really appreciate help from you guys thanks.

**TL;DR** i want to autoclick a button as soon as it pops up with a script

Answer (score -1):

I ran your code through [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6mndwer/) and noticed something. You had `window.addEventListener("DOMcontentloaded", clickButton)` instead of `window.addEventListener("DOMcontentloaded", clickButton())`. see the difference?

```
const clickButton = () => {
        const button =
              document.querySelector("#queue-0-1394263709")
        if (button) button.click()
        else setTimeout(clickButton, 500)
    }
    window.addEventListener("DOMcontentloaded", clickButton())
```

Comment: Hey bloke thanks for helping me out. I tried the solution you gave and it said undefined when i tried running it on chrome dev tools. When i turned it into a script on Tampermonkey it didnt run either.

Comment: My fault, I didn't realize there was no class. Put `#queue-0-1394263709` in place of `.some class`.

Comment: oh i did do that part and there was a small typo when you wrote document so i wrote it properly also but sadly still no dice.

Comment: Are there any other elements with the same Id?

Comment: No I dont think there are maybe i can use something else apart from id?

Comment: You could use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`.

Comment: how do i get an elements tag name btw

Comment: You could use `Elem.tagName`.


[This doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) 
 explains more